# Plot points from one df, plot errorbar from another

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Raw data looks like:

```
Restaurant     Question               rating

McDonalds      How was the food?      5       
McDonalds      How were the drinks?   3     
McDonalds      How were the workers?  2     
Burger_King    How was the food?      1       
Burger_King    How were the drinks?   3       
Burger_King    How were the workers?  4
```

Averages looks like:

```
Question              average_rating    error
How was the food?     3.13              0.7
How were the drinks?  2.37              0.56
```

**How do I make a plot of points (x = question, y = rating, fill = restaurant) with the raw data, then plot the error bars (ymin/ymax = average_rating ± error) on top of it?**

`tribble`s for convenience:

```
tribble(
  ~restaurant, ~question,  ~rating,
  "McDonalds", "How was the food?", 5,
  "McDonalds", "How were the drinks?", 3,
  "McDonalds", "How were the drinks?", 2,
  "BurgerKing", "How was the food?", 1,
  "BurgerKing", "How were the drinks?", 3,
  "BurgerKing", "How were the drinks?", 4
)
```

```
tribble(
  ~question, ~average_rating, ~error,
  "How was the food?", 3.13, 0.7,
  "How were the drinks?", 2.37, 0.56
)
```

Comment: "a plot of points with the raw data" could mean a bunch of things in this context. Please be specific how you want to plot your data.

Comment: How are you going to plot the error bars? You have the errors now by restaurant, not question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw means and error bars on axes in ggplot2 R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689154/how-to-draw-means-and-error-bars-on-axes-in-ggplot2-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired output is not in good agreement with your current dataframes. Because, your second dataframe contains average rating per restaurant and not per question (as outlined by @StupidWolf). So, either, you want to plot with restaurant in x axis and it will be easy to do, or you need to merge both dataframes and set `Average_rating` as a discrete value of the variable `question`.

I do the following for the second option:

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% mutate(question = "Average_rating") %>%
  rename(rating = average_rating) %>% full_join(df1,.) %>%
  mutate(restaurant = sub("BurgerKing","Burger_King",restaurant)) 
Joining, by = c("restaurant", "question", "rating")
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  restaurant  question             rating error
  <chr>       <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl>
1 McDonalds   How was the food?      5    NA   
2 McDonalds   How were the drinks?   3    NA   
3 McDonalds   How were the drinks?   2    NA   
4 Burger_King How was the food?      1    NA   
5 Burger_King How were the drinks?   3    NA   
6 Burger_King How were the drinks?   4    NA   
7 McDonalds   Average_rating         3.13  0.7 
8 Burger_King Average_rating         2.37  0.56
```

Then, if you want to add the plot, you can do the following:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% mutate(question = "Average_rating") %>%
  rename(rating = average_rating) %>% full_join(df1,.) %>%
  mutate(restaurant = sub("BurgerKing","Burger_King",restaurant)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = question, y= rating, color = restaurant))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = rating-error, ymax = rating+error), width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

**EDIT: Ploting error means per questions**

With your new dataframe with the average rate per question, you can use `geom_pointrange` as follow:

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(x = question, y = rating, color = restaurant))+
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2)+
  geom_pointrange(inherit.aes = FALSE,
                  data = df3, 
                  aes(x = question, 
                      y = average_rating,
                      ymin = average_rating-error,
                      ymax = average_rating+error))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: thank you. why did you use `geom_pointrange()` instead of `geom_errorbar()`? Is there a way to make the second error bars look the same as the first?

Comment: You're welcome. `geom_pointrange` is plotting the mean point + error bar in one line. If you want the same appearance than the first one, use `geom_point` and `geom_errorbar` like in the first example.